# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass in Rails with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This will be my last question for today (sorry if I'm asking too fast)

I'm getting the error `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`

It says the problem is on this line: `<td><%= image_tag @map.map.url %></td>`

The whole index code is below:

```
<h1>Listing maps</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Carname</th>
    <th>Map</th>
    <th>Criticalcomponentlocations</th>
    <th>Warnings</th>
    <th>Additionalinfo</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @maps.each do |map| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= map.carname %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag @map.map.url %></td>
    <td><%= map.criticalcomponentlocations %></td>
    <td><%= map.warnings %></td>
    <td><%= map.additionalinfo %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', map %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_map_path(map) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', map, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Map', new_map_path %>
```

Maps Controller, Index:

```
  def index
    @maps = Map.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @maps }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@maps.each` loop, you're trying to access a (probably) non-existent `@map` instance variable when you *should* be accessing the `map` variable that is local to your loop.

Try this instead:

```
<% @maps.each do |map| %>
  <tr>
    ...
    <td><%= image_tag map.map.url %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well, now I'm getting `undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: What is the content of the `index` action of your maps controller? Please post it to your question.

Comment: Can you verify whether `Map` actually has the attribute `url`? If you go into your Rails console (by typing `rails c` in your command line), what is the output if you type `Map`?

Comment: If it helps at all, I'm using the Paperclip gem. ` => Map(id: integer, carname: string, criticalcomponentlocations: text, warnings: text, additionalinfo: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, map_file_name: string, map_content_type: string, map_file_size: integer, map_updated_at: datetime) `

Comment: Is Paperclip attached to the `map` attribute of the `Map` model? If so, you'd access the URL through `map.map.url`. I've updated my answer to reflect. If this doesn't work, please update your answer to show your `Map` model in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you wish to use, map, is not an instance variable.  It is a local variable, so you should use 'map.url' instead of '@map.map.url'

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code `<td><%= image_tag @map.map.url %></td>` uses an instance variable `@map`, but you're inside the scope of the enumerator `<% @maps.each do |map| %>`. You should use the `map.url` local variable instead of `@map.map.url`.